# SEVERE: Error creating the repository Refer to the logfiles at D:app/hp/cfgtools/logs.. in oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

SEVERE: Error creating the repository Refer to the logfiles at

When I want to created a repository for start db console following error occured
SEVERE: Error creating the repository Refer to the logfiles at D:app/hp/cfgtoolslogs/ecma/orcl...

.Guide What I do

I Used following steps
        emca -repos create

```
    Enter the following information:
 Database SID: prod9
  Listener port number: 1522
  Password for SYS user:
   Password for SYSMAN user:
  Do you wish to continue? [yes(Y)/no(N)]: Y
```

But its show error not created a repository guide me what I do in oracle 11g?

Comment: And have you looked at the logfiles in that directory as the message instructed you?

Comment: how i looked in logfiles guide me?

Comment: May 25, 2014 10:50:31 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMReposConfig invoke
SEVERE: Error creating the repository
May 25, 2014 10:50:31 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMReposConfig invoke
INFO: Refer to the log file at D:\app\hp\cfgtoollogs\emca\orcl\emca_repos_create_<date>.log for more details.
May 25, 2014 10:50:31 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig perform
SEVERE: Error creating the repository
Refer to the log file at D:\app\hp\cfgtoollogs\emca\orcl\emca_2014_05_25_10_49_52.log for more details.
May 25, 2014 10:50:31 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig perform

Comment: Open Explorer, navigate to the directory, open the file with a text editor (Notepad if you haven't got a better one) .